# Chain dynamic iterable of context managers to a single with statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, iterable, chain

I have a bunch of context managers that I want to chain. On the first glance, `contextlib.nested` looked like a fitting solution. However, this method is flagged as deprecated in the documentation which also states that the latest `with` statement allows this directly:

> Deprecated since version 2.7: The with-statement now supports this
>   functionality directly (without the confusing error prone quirks).

However I could not get Python 3.4.3 to use a dynamic iterable of context managers:

```
class Foo():
    def __enter__(self):
        print('entering:', self.name)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *_):
        pass
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

foo = Foo('foo')
bar = Foo('bar')
```

whether chaining:

```
from itertools import chain
m = chain([foo], [bar])
with m:
     pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
m = [foo, bar]
```

providing the list directly:

```
with m:
     pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
```

or unpacking:

```
with (*m):
    pass

  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

So, how do I properly chain a dynamic amount of context managers in a `with` statement correctly?

Comment: `with` doesn't take an iterable, no. `with` takes *multiple contextmanagers*, but not as a list.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's bad news. So I would need to write a chaining class on my own?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You misunderstood that line. The `with` statement takes more than one context manager, separated by commas, but *not* an iterable:

```
with foo, bar:
```

works.

Use a [`contextlib.ExitStack()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) if you need to support a *dynamic* set of context managers:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    for cm in (foo, bar):
        stack.enter_context(cm)
```

Answer (score 0):

The *"multiple manager form of the `with` statement"*, as shown in [the statement's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with), would be:

```
with foo, bar:
```

i.e. it *doesn't* support a dynamic number of managers. As [the documentation for `contextlib.nested`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) notes:

> Developers that need to support nesting of a variable number of
>   context managers can either use the `warnings` module to suppress the
>   `DeprecationWarning` raised by this function or else use this function
>   as a model for an application specific implementation.