# What's the best way to read a text file from within a tar archive as strings (not byte strings)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tarfile

I have some text files I need to process (but not extract) from a tar archive. I have working python 2 code which I am trying to uplift to python 3. Unfortunately python 3 is returning byte strings which the rest of the code cannot process correctly. I need to convert the byte strings to strings. A simple example looks like this:

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open("file.tar") as tar:
    with tar.extractfile("test.txt") as extracted:
        lines = extracted.readlines()
        print(lines)
```

The result is:

```
['a\n', 'test\n', 'file\n']    # python 2
[b'a\n', b'test\n', b'file\n'] # python 3
```

Below are some current attempts at fixing, which work, however it feels awkward that I would need to use a triple with statement, list comprehension or map just to read some text:

```
with io.TextIOWrapper(extracted) as txtextracted:
    lines = txtextracted.readlines()

# or
lines = [i.decode("utf-8") for i in lines]

# or
lines = list(map(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8"),lines))
```

I cannot find a neater solution in the `io.BufferedReader` documentation (this is the object which `TarFile.extractfile` returns). I have tried to come up with solutions but none are as neat as the python 2 solution. Is there a neat and pythonic way to parse the tar file's `io.BufferedReader` object as strings?

Comment: the title should be modifed, at first glance it is talking about the best way, but actually you are asking how to port the python 2 code to python 3.

Comment: Would wrapping the `txtextracted` object in a `io.TextIOWrapper` instance be good enough?

Comment: "Is there a neat and pythonic way to parse the tar file's io.BufferedReader object as strings?" Not really, at least as far as I can tell. Fundamentally, the `tarfile` library has no reason to expect the files in the archive to represent textual data; and `explicit is better than implicit`. I guess you could try `.extract`ing directly to a temp file, and then parsing that. That's only two context managers, which don't have to be nested. It does mean a temp file, though.

Comment: If you don't like the standard library design, there's a mailing list to talk about that. But "best way" questions usually aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, you can simplify the two `with` into a single one: `with io.TextIOWrapper(tar.extractfile('test.txt')) as f: print(f.readlines())`

Comment: IMO `lines = [i.decode("utf-8") for i in lines]` is the best way and least amount of work.

Answer (score 3):

The `with` statement [allows for multiple context managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30981706/chain-dynamic-iterable-of-context-managers-to-a-single-with-statement), and as it turns out, their construction may depend on previous ones in the chain - example:

```py
class manager:
    def __init__(self, name, child=None):
        self.name, self.child = name, child
    def __exit__(self, t, value, traceback):
        print('exiting', self)
    def __enter__(self):
        print('entering', self)
        return self
    def __str__(self):
        childname = None if self.child is None else f"'{self.child.name}'"
        return f"manager '{self.name}' with child {childname}"
```

Testing it:

```
>>> with manager('x') as x, manager('y', x) as y, manager('z', y) as z: pass
...
entering manager 'x' with child None
entering manager 'y' with child 'x'
entering manager 'z' with child 'y'
exiting manager 'z' with child 'y'
exiting manager 'y' with child 'x'
exiting manager 'x' with child None
```

Thus:

```py
with tarfile.open("file.tar") as tar, tar.extractfile("test.txt") as binary, io.TextIOWrapper(binary) as text:
    lines = text.readlines()
```

(Although I don't think you really *need* to manage all those contexts anyway...)